# How to make footnotes start at 1 in each chapter?

Tags: footnotes

In my document the footnotes are numbered sequentially. However, I would like footnote numbering to start at no. 1 in each chapter. I am using the `book` documentclass as it is my understanding that in the `report` and `book` classes, footnotes are numbered inside chapters; in the `article` class footnotes are  throughout the document.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin*{footnote}{chapter}
```

didn't work

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I'm unable to reproduce your problem with a MWE of `\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
Text\footnote{Footnote}.
\chapter{Two}
Text\footnote{Footnote}.
\end{document}`, so the problem must be elsewhere.